# Jquery dynamic rows in form

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

When we click on the link *"Add new row"*, it need to duplicate whole `<div class="row">` and change `<input>` attribute *name* to `data[+1][xxx]`
 *(Number in [] must +1 everytime)*

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/c6WG8/

```
<div class="row">                                  
      <div class="inner">   
        <div>
            <label for="layout_name">Link</label>
            <input id="layout_name" name="data[0][link]" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="layout_name">Text</label>
            <input id="layout_name" name="data[0][text]" type="text" value="">
        </div>
     </div>   
</div>
<a href="#" class="add_row">Add new row</a>
```

First part looks ok, but changing name of input has probably some bug.

Comment: Did you try something or are you just asking us to code it for you ?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Sure, here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/c6WG8/ - first part looks ok (duplicate DIV), but as you can see problem is with rename input name attribute. Do you have idea what's wrong?

Comment: add the fiddle code and link to your question so the effort is shown within the question...many people won't look through the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery fiddle code on line 9, instead of doing

```
content.attr("id",function(i,oldVal) {
```

you should do

```
content.attr("name",function(i,oldVal) {
```

since you want to update the name of the input fields and not the id.  Also, there was a small typo in your code.  You initialized the content variable on line 8 with a dollar sign; you should instead do it like this:

```
var content = $(this).closest('.row').find( "input");
```

An updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6WG8/8/